# Script to Find Copies of Files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hash

I am trying to make a script in PowerShell that analyzes recursevily a directory and gets all hashes MD5 from all files and from all files inside any directories inside the 1st one given.

After that, I want to compare all the hashes between each other to see which one is a copy, and then give an option to delete these copies or not.

At the moment I have this:

```
$UserInput=Read-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse
$someFilePath = $UserInput
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($someFilePath)))
$hash
```

The main problem is in the hash part, that I get an error in calling the "ReadAllBytes".

I also am doubting if creating an array so when I compare the hashes, if they are equal, put the copies in an array, so then deleting them is "easier".

What do you think? (I am also not sure if I am using right the "SomeFilePath", MD5 nor Hash).

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you targeting? You could offload all the file hashing to `Get-FileHash` which will support relative paths and PS provider paths.

Comment: PS.Version: 5.1.14393.1198
BuildVersion 10.0.14393.1198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If targeting PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, I'd use the `Get-FileHash` cmdlet and then group them by hash using the `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
$UserInput = Read-Host
$DuplicateFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse -File |Group {($_|Get-FileHash).Hash} |Where Count -gt 1
foreach($FileGroup in $DuplicateFiles)
{
    Write-Host "These files share hash $($FileGroup.Name)"
    $FileGroup.Group.FullName |Write-Host
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$fileHashes = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFilePath -Recurse -File | Get-Filehash -Algorithm MD5
$doubles = $fileHashes | Group hash | ? {$_.count -gt 1} | % {$_.Group} 

foreach($item in $doubles) {
  Write-Output $item
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! Is there a way to get the MD5 hash (it's the hash but in hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash | Group Hash | Where Count -gt 1
```

Short version :

```
gci -Path $UserInput -R -File | Get-FileHash | Group Hash | ? Count -gt 1
```